How to Get Rising 'google_trends_queries_list' in DataForSEO API using R
how to extract all Rising related query of Google Trends from DataforSEO API integration into single/one column data frame?
I run below script with no error but still don't get the result. 'res_json' don't show the rising keywords at all.
Setting Live ‘Google Trends Explore’ Tasks documentation:
https://docs.dataforseo.com/v3/keywords_data/google_trends/explore/live/
library(httr) 
library(jsonlite)

username <- "YOUR_EMAIL" 
password <- "YOUR_API_PASSWORD"

headers = c(   `Authorization` = paste('Basic',base64_enc(paste0(username,":",password))),   `Content-Type` = 'application/json' )

data = paste0('[{"api": "keywords_data","function": "explore","se": "google_trends","location_code": 2840,"category_code": 0,"type": "web","time_range": "past_7_days","keywords": ["coffee","coffee machine","coffee shop"]}]')

res <- POST(url = 'https://api.dataforseo.com/v3/keywords_data/google_trends/explore/live', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)

res_text <- content(res, "text")

res_json <- fromJSON(res_text, flatten = TRUE)


I used the rjsoncons CRAN package and the JMESPath query language.
library(rjsoncons)

The short answer might be something like (depending on the specifics of your query)
query <- "
tasks[].result[].items[?type=='google_trends_queries_list'].data.rising | 
[][]"
j_pivot(json, query, as = "data.frame")

To explain this, I looked at the page you reference, which includes the response schema and a side-bar with an example query / response. I copied the full example response into R (I'm showing just the first few lines)
json <- '{
  "version": "0.1.20220420",
  "status_code": 20000,
  "status_message": "Ok.",
  ...

and then explored it interactively
listviewer::jsonedit(json)

The response is an object with a 'tasks' field. The 'tasks' field is an array of objects, each containing a 'result' field. The 'result' field is an array of objects, each containing a 'items' field. The 'items' field is an array of objects, each containing a 'type' field. The 'type' field identifies the information in the item. To find the type of each item, I used the following JMESPath expression, and the j_query() function to query the JSON object
query <- "tasks[].result[].items[].type"
j_query(json, query)
## ["google_trends_graph","google_trends_map","google_trends_topics_list","google_trends_queries_list"] 

Good, there is a 'google_trends_queries_list' in the response. I updated the query to select just this item using items[?type == 'google_trends_queries_list'], then looked at the 'data' object and 'rising' array
query <- "tasks[].result[].items[?type=='google_trends_queries_list'].data.rising"
j_query(json, query)
## [[[]]]

For this particular response, the 'rising' field consists of a zero-length array.
Let's use 'google_trends_topics_list' to continue the example. The following query tells me that there are 15 'rising' elements in this item
query <- "tasks[].result[].items[?type=='google_trends_topics_list'].data.rising"

j_query(json, query) returns an array-of-array-of-array of rising topics. The JMESPath expression can be modified to 'unpack' this to an array of rising topics using the pipe operator | and two levels of unpacking
query <- "
tasks[].result[].items[?type=='google_trends_topics_list'].data.rising | 
[][]"

Finally, this list-of-rising topics can be represented as a data.frame or tibble using j_pivot()
j_pivot(json, query, as = "tibble")
## # A tibble: 15 × 4
##    topic_id   topic_title                           topic_type             value
##    <chr>      <chr>                                 <chr>                  <int>
##  1 /m/086df   Web design                            Discipline               400
##  2 /m/07xy0   Uniform Resource Locator              Topic                    250
##  3 /m/02cwm   Design                                Topic                    140
##  4 /m/055t58  Google Maps                           Website                  130
##  5 /m/05x35   Plug-in                               Computing                 90
##  6 /m/026sq   Data                                  Topic                     80
##  7 /m/07k1x   Tool                                  Topic                     80
##  8 /m/081rb   Writing                               Language writing syst…    70
##  9 /m/085n4   Website                               Topic                     70
## 10 /m/05z1_   Python                                Programming language      60
## 11 /m/0bngkg  Yelp                                  Company                   60
## 12 /m/03l68z  Google Ads                            Topic                     60
## 13 /m/02x3zp_ Content                               Media                     50
## 14 /m/05fbf64 Google APIs                           Topic                     50
## 15 /m/05s_jbn Application programming interface key Topic                     50

